# How to set a specific title to a HAML page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to set the name for my index page to "Your studio".

I used this:

```
%head
    %title ABCDE
%body
    blablablabla...
```

It did not appear to work. Please help to solve this simple question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your layout, you can use:

```
%head
  %title= yield(:title)
```

And in your view:

```
= content_for(:title, "ABCDE")
```

Without repeating the `head` and `title` tags. Also you should only use the `body`tag in the layout.

Comment: where is my layout? Is it index.html? Sorry im new to this, not sure what you mean

Comment: No problem, this is the `app/views/layouts/application.html`file.